# Why am I getting a query performance increase?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

### Intro

Simple question, I want to understand what makes queries faster. I've currently been asked to improve the performance of a query, and I have, **but**, this is the best part, I'm not sure as to how or why it's faster, but it's dramatically faster.

This isn't really essential to explain as to why the second query is so much faster, I've only included this in the event that you were wondering. Basically, we want to initially find a huge collection of data, I mean every combination that's valid. Hence why I think the 'top(1)' part of the old query is actually invalid.

---

### Example Code

The original query ran something like this

```
SELECT 
 ... 
(SELECT TOP(1) v FROM pat pa WHERE pa.pc = p.c AND pa.ki = 64) AS pt, 
(SELECT TOP(1) v FROM pat pa2 WHERE pa2.pc = p.c AND pa2.ki = 17) AS col
...
```

So this took a surprising amount of time, so I changed it to something more like this:

```
SELECT 
...
pt.v, col.v
...

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT v, pc
    FROM pat
    WHERE ki = 64
    GROUP BY v, pc
) AS pt
ON p.c = pt.pc

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT v, pc
    FROM pat
    WHERE ki = 17
    GROUP BY v, pc
) AS col
ON p.c = col.pc
```

---

### Review

The first query would take over twice as long to execute, literally, I mean the performance increase is over doubled, and it actually brings back more data too, which is also a good thing in this situation.

I'd just like it if someone could explain as to why the second one is so much faster? - I've worked out that it takes about 20% of the time of the original query, retrieves more records, etc.

---

### Additionally

Can you give me as many dos and donts, as well as pros and cons to what to do and not to do when it comes to writing queries? - How can I get the best performance every single time?

I also just wrote one query, and doing it in a certain way makes an **INSANE** difference in terms of performance.

#### First Query - The Slow One

```
SELECT DISTINCT pa.v, pa.pc, pa.kid, ak.dn, ak.ID
FROM pat AS pa 
INNER JOIN akt AS ak 
ON pa.kid = ak.id
```

#### Second Query - Lightning Fast

```
   WITH prodAts AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT v, pc, kid
        FROM pat
    ),

    aks AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT dn, ID
        FROM akt
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM prodAts 
    INNER JOIN aks 
    ON prodAts.kid = aks.ID
```

I mean to generate 1 row with the first query, it takes the same time to generate all rows with the second query, and I genuinely have no idea how that's the case? - **Please explain?**

Comment: It's a simple question, but it has a myriad of answers. Libraries have been written on the subject. I've voted to close as too broad.

Comment: Look at, or read how to interpret the execution plans. All the answers are in there.

Comment: I guess execution plans sounds like a good start, I don't actually have access to the server, I just write the queries, so I don't even know what tables are indexed and what ones are not, etc. But It's worth me looking into it by the sounds of it?

Comment: How can you do your job if you can't access the server and are missing vital information about the server?? It's like asking a French mechanic to fix a car in England without moving!

Comment: I literally have to ask the senior developers, and do a fair share of guess work.... Insane I know.... It does sometimes make me wanna pull my hair out... But turns out I've become very good at it now... I actually love your comparison, because that's how it feels half the time!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a clear cut answer to what is best, the only answer is "it depends". There are many factors to take into account when performance tuning for your system ranging from table sizes, indexes, disk speed, cpu speed and allowances, amount of paralelism, statement sequencing, available memory. whether the query needs to spill over into temp db... The list goes on.

As the comments stated, we can only really speculate on why your queries ran faster in your examples unless we saw some query plans (which tell you exactly what each of the queries is actually doing).

For the second block the only thing that comes to mind is poor indexing on the base tables, The CTE is pulling the data into memory and then joining them together and so has a full view on the form and structure of the data it is manipulating. The direct join approach has a quick scan of the tables/checks the stored metrics of the tables and makes a guess at the best way to join them together (there are multiple internal join methods for the optimizer to use). 
If those metrics are bad/not representative of what is currently stored there is a good chance the optimizer is making a bad decision.

Following on from your comment in the question, yes having access to the state of the server and the plans is best (plans at least they will tell you which indexes etc it is using). Otherwise your performance tuning is just stabbing in the dark and whilst you may get lucky and make some gains today, a db maintenance task may run tonight restructuring all of the data causing your new queries to actually be the least optimal choices (it can happen).

The best piece of advice I can give you in regards to performance tuning is to identify "why is the current solution bad" over "why is the new one good" This will guide you into making better calls with your tuning.

Comment: Honestly, I'm still new to this, so even very vague answers like 'it depends', it's better than no answer, although it leads to more questions, that's not the point. Tank you for your input! :) .... And yeah, my performance benchmarks are me just guessing on how to get the same output, only getting it done faster, how, it's down to luck/guess work.... As for the pro tip at the end, I'll be sure to keep that in mind for future! :)

Comment: @joeevans996 the best thing in your situation is to push internally that your job will be much simpler if you had access to the query plans. It's great that you are currently seeing results with your work, but I do think having the plans to hand would make your output much more consistent.

Comment: Okay, so interesting fact, APPARENTLY, when you remove the word distinct, it'll have the EXACT same execution plan. However, still performs MUCH faster, I asked one of the senior developers to take a look, he said I've broken his brain, so it looks like your theory was possibly right? I don't know?

Comment: i'd have thought the distinct would either check whether they are unique using the index or use a sort so it can identify distinction. If it's using the index (most likely if they have the exact query plan) and the index is bad it will take longer. Try rebuilding the indexes on the table and running. the original query. Could be a case of poor table maintenace.I would recomend a group by instead of a distinct anyway if you need to ensure uniqueness as that resolves before the select wheras distinct is after